# copy data from last row and paste it in next 6 blank rows but its not going through...your kind help will be inevitable

Tags: copy, row, paste

```
LASTROW = Worksheets("master log-1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'
''With LASTROW
'
'Worksheets("master log-1").Range("B" & LASTROW - 1, "I" & LASTROW).Copy
'
'Worksheets("master log-1").Range("B" & LASTROW + 6, "I" & LASTROW + 6).Paste
''End With
```

Comment: Worksheets("master log-1").Range("B" & LASTROW + 6, "I" & LASTROW + 6).Paste showing debug error on this line

Comment: i removed the -1 and it is pasting on 6th rows from last row,but it is required to paste all 6 rows in between also..how to achieve this